# Kubernetes: List all available API servers

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way in Kubernetes to list all API endpoints currently available? So that I can get an updated list of all possible API endpoints as long as I have at least one valid API endpoint.

Comment: Do you mean something like that `$ kubectl get ep --all-namespaces`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in Kubernetes to list all API endpoints currently available?

Yes, there is. You can get all the endpoints with `kubectl` command:

`$ kubectl get endpoints --all-namespaces`

You could type a shorter version of above command:

`$ kubectl get ep -A` ( `-A`from version 1.14 and newer)

Output of above command should look like that:

```sh
NAMESPACE     NAME                             ENDPOINTS                                            AGE
default       hello-service                    10.32.0.10:50001,10.32.1.18:50001,10.32.2.3:50001    14s
default       kubernetes                       AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:443                                  18h
kube-system   default-http-backend             10.32.0.9:8080                                       18h
kube-system   gcp-controller-manager           <none>                                               18h
kube-system   heapster                         10.32.1.3:8082                                       18h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager          <none>                                               18h
kube-system   kube-dns                         10.32.0.6:53,10.32.2.2:53,10.32.0.6:53 + 1 more...   18h
kube-system   kube-scheduler                   <none>                                               18h
kube-system   managed-certificate-controller   <none>                                               18h
kube-system   metrics-server                   10.32.1.2:443                                        18h
```

Take a specific look on:

```
default       kubernetes                       AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:443                                  18h
```

It's a point of contact to your Kubernetes cluster.

You can also use `$ kubectl describe endpoint EP_NAME` to get more information:

```
Name:         hello-service
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time: 2020-02-28T06:30:22Z
Subsets:
  Addresses:          10.32.0.10,10.32.1.18,10.32.2.3
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name     Port   Protocol
    ----     ----   --------
    <unset>  50001  TCP

Events:  <none>
```

Please refer to additional resources:

- [Kubernetes.io: API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/)
- [Kubernetes.io: Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/)
- [Theithollow.com: Kubernetes endpoints](https://theithollow.com/2019/02/04/kubernetes-endpoints/)

Let me know if you have any questions to that.

Comment: So an endpoint in the default namespace named kubernetes is always and API endpoint?

Comment: Endpoint that I showed above is one of the many ways to access Kubernetes API. Please refer to 1.[Kubernetes.io: Access cluster API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/) 2. [Oreilly: Managing Kubernetes](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/managing-kubernetes/9781492033905/ch04.html). Please write your question once more if it's possible because it's hard for me to understand what you meant by it.